# axios response interceptor strange behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

This is my fetch function:

```js
let fetch = async (data, method, url, responseType, header) => {
  axios.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {
      // Do something with response data
      return response;
    },
    function (error) {
      let errorObj;
      console.log(error);
      switch (true) {
        case error.response !== undefined:
          switch (error.response.status) {
            case 401:
              errorObj = {
                status: 401,
                message: error.response.data,
              };
              break;
            case 404:
              errorObj = {
                status: 404,
                message: error.message,
              };
              break;
            default:
              errorObj = {
                status: error.response.status,
                message: error.response.statusText,
              };
              break;
          }
          break;
        case error.request !== undefined:
          errorObj = error.request;
          break;
        default:
          errorObj = { message: error.message };
          break;
      }
      return Promise.reject(errorObj);
    }
  );
  let theRealURL = process.env["REACT_APP_SOCKET_URL"] + url;
  let requestObj = { method: method, url: theRealURL };
  if (method.toLowerCase() === "get") {
    requestObj.params = data;
  } else {
    requestObj.data = data;
  }
  if (responseType) {
    requestObj["responseType"] = responseType;
  }
  if (header) {
    requestObj["headers"] = header;
  }
  try {
    let response = await axios(requestObj);
    if (response.request.responseType === "blob") {
      let fileName = response.headers["content-disposition"];
      fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("filename=") + 9);
      const newBlob = new Blob([response.data], {
        type: response.headers.get("content-type"),
      });
      const objUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
      let link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = objUrl;
      link.download = fileName;
      link.click();
    }
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
```

I have some APIs that are required to authenticate before calling them.
When the session time out, I browse a page that calls those APIs through a link,
The following messages are shown in the console:

[image]

Where line 175 is:

[image]

My problem is why line 175 is called three times.

However, when I refresh the web page by pressing the "F5" button, it works fine.

[image]

Comment: You appear to be adding an interceptor each time you call `fetch`. Interceptors are intended to be added once to an Axios instance, not repeatedly

Comment: Is it possible to solve the problem by creating an individual fetch object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be adding an interceptor each time you call `fetch()`. Interceptors are intended to be added once to an Axios instance, not repeatedly.

This is why you see repeated log lines for the same thing. Each interceptor added is like a link in a chain.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#multiple-interceptors)

> #### Multiple Interceptors
>
> Given you add multiple response interceptors and when the response was fulfilled
>
> - then each interceptor is executed
> - then they are executed in the order they were added

The better option is to configure your Axios instance *once* and use that instance to make your requests.

For example

```js
// create and configure an instance
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_URL,
});

// add the response interceptor
api.interceptors.response.use(
  null, // default success handler
  (error) => {
    console.warn(error.toJSON());

    return Promise.reject({
      status: error.response?.status,
      message:
        error.response?.data ?? error.response?.statusText ?? error.message,
    });
  },
  {
    synchronous: true, // optimise interceptor handling
  }
);

const fetch = async (data, method, url, responseType, headers) => {
  const requestObj = {
    url,
    method,
    responseType,
    headers,
    [method.toLowerCase() === "get" ? "params" : "data"]: data,
  };

  const response = await api(requestObj); // use the created instance

  if (response.request.responseType === "blob") {
    let fileName = response.headers["content-disposition"];
    fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("filename=") + 9);
    const newBlob = new Blob([response.data], {
      type: response.headers.get("content-type"),
    });
    const objUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = objUrl;
    link.download = fileName;
    link.click();
  }
  return response.data;
};
```