# Problem about calling async/await in react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

Here is a RosterDataUtil.js

```
import FetchAPI from "./FetchAPI";
import { Utility } from "./Utility";
export default class RosterDataUtil {
    constructor(){
        let fetchAPI = new FetchAPI();
        let roster = null;
        ............
        this.init = async (weekdayNames) => {
            roster = { activeShiftList: await fetchAPI.getActiveShiftList()};
            roster.weekdayNames = weekdayNames;
        }
        this.loadData = async (year, month, noOfWorkingDay) => {
            roster.year = year;
            roster.month = month;
            roster.rosterRow = await fetchAPI.getRoster(year, month);
            console.log(roster.rosterRow);
        }
        ...........................
    }       
}
```

Here is FetchAPI.js:

```
import axios from "axios";
export default class FetchAPI {
    constructor() {
        this.getRoster = async (year, month) => {
            return (await fetch({ year: year, month: month }, "get", "/rosterWeb/publicAPI/getRoster"));
        }
        //================================================================================================================
        // create and configure an axios instance
        // src:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76116501/axios-response-interceptor-strange-behavior?noredirect=1#comment134237075_76116501
        const api = axios.create({
            baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_URL,
        });
        // add the response interceptor
        api.interceptors.response.use(
            null, // default success handler
            (error) => {
                console.log(error.toJSON());
                return Promise.reject({
                    status: error.response?.status,
                    message:
                        error.response?.data ?? error.response?.statusText ?? error.message,
                });
            },
            {
                synchronous: true, // optimise interceptor handling
            }
        );

        const fetch = async (data, method, url, responseType, headers) => {
            const requestObj = {
                url,
                method,
                responseType,
                headers,
                [method.toLowerCase() === "get" ? "params" : "data"]: data,
            };
            const response = await api(requestObj); // use the created instance
            if (response.request.responseType === "blob") {
                let fileName = response.headers["content-disposition"];
                console.log(fileName);
                let firstIndex = fileName.indexOf("filename=");
                fileName = fileName.substring(firstIndex + 9);

                const newBlob = new Blob([response.data]);
                const objUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
                const link = document.createElement("a");
                link.href = objUrl;
                link.download = fileName;
                link.click();
            }
            return response.data;
        };
    }
}
```

When I call in my hook

```
import { useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import CalendarUtility from "../../util/calendar/CalendarUtility";
import RosterDataUtil from "./RosterDataUtill";

let reducer = (state, action) => {
    let result = { ...state };
    switch (action.type) {
        case "init":
            result.monthlyCalendar = action.monthlyCalendar;
            result.roster = result.rosterDataUtil.getRoster();           
            result.isLoading = false;
            break;
        case "setError":
            result.error = action.error;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
export function useTestRoster() {
    const [itemList, updateItemList] = useReducer(reducer, {
        calendarUtility: new CalendarUtility(),
        monthlyCalendar: null,
        error: null,
        isLoading: true,
        roster: null,
        rosterDataUtil: new RosterDataUtil(),
        systemParam: null,
    });
    useEffect(() => {
        let systemUtil = new SystemUtil();
        let getData = async () => {
            try{
                let now = new Date();
                let rosterYear = now.getFullYear();
                let rosterMonth = now.getMonth();
                let monthlyCalendar = itemList.calendarUtility.getMonthlyCalendar(rosterYear, rosterMonth);
                await itemList.rosterDataUtil.init(itemList.calendarUtility.weekdayNames);
                await itemList.rosterDataUtil.loadData(rosterYear, rosterMonth + 1, monthlyCalendar.noOfWorkingDay);
                updateItemList({
                    monthlyCalendar,
                    type: "init"
                });
            }catch (error){
                console.log(error);
                updateItemList({ "error": error, "type": "setError" });
            }
        }
        getData();
    }, []);
    
    return {
        error: itemList.error,
        isLoading: itemList.isLoading,
        roster: itemList.roster,

    }
}
```

The following statement:

```
console.log(roster.rosterRow);
```

returns `undefined` first, after some time it returns the expected value.

It seems that the following statement has not been awaited.

```
roster.rosterRow = await fetchAPI.getRoster(year, month);
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: `rosterSchedulerDataUtil.init(weekdayNames)`.  You seem to have forgotten to await that bit.

Comment: You are not `await`ing the `init()` call. "*When I call it in my hook, it works fine*" - I really doubt that

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code accordingly. My focus is the variable `roster.rosterRow` not else.

Comment: Please post the complete code of the "hook" as well as the implementation of `getRoster`

Comment: Source code added.